# How do I start an activity from within a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a set of tabs inside of a `FragmentActivity` that each hold their own fragment. When I tried to start a new activity from within that fragment via an `onClickListener`, and using the `startActivity(myIntent)` method, my application force closes.

After looking around for a while, I found a reference or two to a method called `startActivityFromFragment`, but after searching around for an hour or so I can't find any explanations or examples of how to use it or whether this is what I should be using.

I guess what I'm asking is whether there is any difference between launching a new activity from an activity, and launching a new activity from a fragment, and if so, what do I need to implement?

Comment: Post the code and the logcat output for when the app force closes

Comment: `FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment()` is called by `Fragment.startActivityForResult()` to implement its behavior, and `Activity.startActivityFromFragment()` is called when a Fragment in this activity calls its `startActivity()`. We don't need to call them directly.

Answer (score 50):

You should do it with `getActivity().startActivity(myIntent)`

Comment: I actually just tried that on a hunch - within the onClickListener I have an intent set up, and then I call the getActivity().startActivity(myIntent) - do I have to add anything else in particular to end the fragment or activity?

Comment: @EkKoZ : This is not necessary. The `startActivity(Intent intent)` method of `Fragment` effectively does the same thing.

Comment: that´s for sure, but i thought it could be an scope problem with the context

Comment: not working showing blank screen.activity onCreate() method is calling from its showing a simple Blank screen.

Comment: Make sure though that getActivity() doesnt return null because a Fragment is not attached to the Activity at it's birth

Answer (score 45):

I done it, below code is working for me....

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);

        Button newPage = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.click);
        newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

and Please make sure that your destination activity should be register in Manifest.xml file,

but in my case all tabs are not shown in HomeActivity, is any solution for that ?

Comment: it works for me now .. but I don't understand how it works :-( .. why cant I just use onClick method directly ? ..

Comment: how can i use a backstack here

Answer (score 13):

The difference between starting an Activity from a Fragment and an Activity is how you get the context, because in both cases it has to be an activity.

**From an activity:**
The context is the current activity (`this`)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**From a fragment:**
The context is the parent activity (`getActivity()`). Notice, that the fragment itself can start the activity via `startActivity()`, this is not necessary to be done from the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What if I have a fragmentactivity?

Comment: @Euridice01 Because`FragmentActivity` extends `Activity`, you can use `this` as the context, just like from a normal activity. More info can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39733562

Comment: One more thing, what about BindingFragmentActivity?I can't find anything on that online.

Comment: @Euridice01 If you mean `BindingFragmentActivity` from the androidbound library, then `BindingFragmentActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, which, as mentioned above extends `Activity`.
I have never used the androidbound library, but from what it looks like, `BindingFragmentActivity` isn't supported anymore (don't quote me on that).

Answer (score 6):

I do it like this, to launch the SendFreeTextActivity from a (custom) menu fragment that appears in multiple activities:

In the MenuFragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

    final Button sendFreeTextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendFreeTextButton);
    sendFreeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sendFreeTextButton clicked");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SendFreeTextActivity.class);
            MenuFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Base Context of the Activity in which your fragment resides to start an Intent.

```
Intent j = new Intent(fBaseCtx, NewactivityName.class);         
startActivity(j);
```

where `fBaseCtx` is `BaseContext` of your current activity.
You can get it as `fBaseCtx = getBaseContext();`