# How to move from a one fragment to an activity

Tags: android, fragment

I am working on a `CustomListView` for a fragment and `CustomAdapter` extends from `BaseAdapter` . In my `CustomAdapter` there is button on click that button i want to move a activity but i don't know how to switch from one fragment to an activity.

Comment: 1) adapter cannot have a Button or any other kind of View, 2) you cannot move an Activity 3) so what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: He wants to move to an Activity, I suppose and not move an activity :)

Comment: "move to an Activity" ? you cannot neither move Activity nor move to an Activity... what you can do is to start an Activity...

Comment: This is not a grammar class! He wants to start a new Activity. You need sleep mate :)

Comment: @Skynet i have a textView in customadapter and from that i want to move to another activity can i move or not.

Comment: You can mate, you can move anywhere. Just put your code right. set an onClickListener on your textView and call the function I posted below from that onClickListener.

Comment: @Skynet but this code is not working in customadapter that extends from baseadapter

Comment: You my friend must post some code and show us what is not working.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void moveToNewActivity () {

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    ((Activity) getActivity()).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

}
```

`overridePendingTransition(0,0);` means no Animation in transition.

[Check This](https://github.com/simonjrp/ESCAPE/blob/b24b9e84fdc602493955f7c91beab239f7ab8152/ESCAPE/src/se/chalmers/dat255/group22/escape/BlocksFragment.java), it will give you a fair idea of how an onClickListener is used to start a new Activity, from within a Fragment.

Comment: startActivity method can't be accessed in a fragment like you said. It has to call this method using a context which is returned using getActivity().

Comment: I am using the above code in a Production project with around 10000 downloads and I dont find any issues. It is supplied with a context, if you may consider reading through.

Comment: Yes but not inside a class that extends Fragment instead of class that extends Activity

Comment: Inside of  a class that extends Fragment. Try this out :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074608/how-do-i-start-an-activity-from-within-a-fragment

Comment: This is the code I suggested you to use, show us how you are implementing it?

Comment: @skynet my bad... I donno how could I skip it. But yes that method exist in fragment class as well. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for this in Kotlin with databinding, perform this within your Fragment class:

```js
binding.openActivityButton.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this@YourFragmentName.requireContext(), YourActivityName::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Replace `YourFragmentName` with the name of your fragment and `YourActivityName` with the name of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

for one fragment use: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(yourFragment).commit();`