# Error With StartActivityForResult and Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

i tried to convert activity into fragment and the code is without "errors" in android studio, but the app crashes when the converted activity is pressed.

part of code i think its causing error:

```
Btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            getActivity().finish();
         }});
```

and my error output:

```
04-19 15:54:33.644  32229-32229/com.app.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.test, PID: 32229
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app.test/com.app.test.ChangePassword}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

could this part of code that i pasted cause this problem ?

Comment: Check if you have Register.class declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all your activities registered in manifest.
[howto for sliding tabs](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

Comment: should i register fragment in manifest because i dont have any activity, only mainactivity and it is registered.

Comment: @Sh4rk162, You can't "start" Fragments via Intents

Comment: what is the type of `Register.class`? And what is `com.app.test.ChangePassword`?

Comment: Intents works only with activities. If you want to switch fragments in one activity use `FragmentManager`, if you want start activity for result - add another activities which displays your fragments on start.

Comment: @Raiv
maybe a simpler question how can i make slider menu, with login/register and "news feed" the easiest way. fragments or combination of fragments and activities 

is it something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074608/how-do-i-start-an-activity-from-within-a-fragment

Comment: I added guide for sliding tabs in my answer

Comment: yes i saw but i want to know if its possible to do it on the way i pasted the link to run activity inside fragment, because its easier to understand
thanks

Comment: yes,you can run activity from fragment. But not fragment from fragment.