# Navigate to Activity from fragment on button onclick

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to navigate to a new activity from my fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.map);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Map.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

I want to navigate from home fragment to new class activity map.

Comment: Make your question clear by commenting in the code what you are trying to do or Where you have a problem.

Comment: What's going wrong? At first glance your code seems like it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start an activity from within a Fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074608/how-do-i-start-an-activity-from-within-a-fragment)

Comment: @Shabin, Code looks fine. Did you add activity in manifest file?

Comment: Replace getActivity().startActivity(i) with startActivity(i)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Map.class);
startActivity(intent);
```